# Easy to use tool to send screenshots from a website?

Tags: testing

Is there tool or widget that I can embed in my site that would allow visitors sending me a screenshot of the current page?

It would be helpful for reporting errors they encounter on the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Jotform](http://www.jotform.com/) has a nice form service and recently added a form template called [wishbox](http://www.jotform.com/blog/40-Wishbox-Released-An-Amazing-New-Way-to-Get-Feedback-from-Web-Site-Visitors) that is easily embeddable as a slid out tab on  any page which can send a screenshot with comments. I have not used wishbox yet, but I do use Jotform and like their service. You can easily sign up for their free option and test it out within 5 minutes.

Comment: that's exactly what I had in mind - thanks a ton !!!

Comment: Hope it works out for you.

Comment: It does. SE doesn't let me award the bounty yet, but it's coming ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This may not be a complete answer, but it is one that will work.

You could include a link to [Awesome Screenshot](http://awesomescreenshot.com/) so the user can install the screenshot plugin. The plugin is available for Chrome, Firefox and Safari. Fireshot is available for [Internet Explorer](http://download.cnet.com/FireShot-for-Internet-Explorer/3000-12512_4-10862847.html).

Or better yet, you could write browser specific code so the user will be taken to the download/install page of the screenshot plugin you choose for each browser.

Comment: thanks. Is there a way to take a screen shot without having the user install a tool or plugin?

Comment: alt+ PrintScreen snaps the current Window

Answer (score 2):

There are analytics programs such as `clicktale.com` that record user sessions. It's intended as a means to uncover usability issues rather then help with trouble tickets, however, if you find users are getting stuck in the same place or experiencing the same problem you can add the tracking to that page and it should help you uncover what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Bugherd](http://www.bugherd.com/)  might be just what you need. I've used it on a few websites and works really well in bug reporting (specially if you've got a big audience). They've got 30 day trial which you might want to check.

If you're using WordPress, this [plugin](http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/bm-shots-automated-screenshots-website/) (WordPress website screenshot) might be useful also.

Comment: [Usersnap](http://usersnap.com) is also worth a try. You will get accurate screenshots and annotations from your visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 has a wonderful, built-in 'Snipping Tool'.